# Complex mapping of an annulus problem

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I am having a hard time understanding how to set up this map.

$f$ maps the annulus holomorphically onto itself but permutes the inner and outer boundaries $|z| = a$ and $|z| = b$, $0 < a < b$. Find the expression for $f$.

I have tried to rescale a to 1 among other things, but for some reason, I fail to see how can I set up this map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $w = \dfrac{ab}{z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome!